# Yii2 via table is not using JOIN?

Tags: php, yii2

i have few tables in mysql:

**user**:

`|id|name|
 |1 |test|
 |2 |test|
 |3 |test|
 |4 |test|`

**subscribes**:

`|user_id|ref_user_id|created_on|
 |2      |1          |1000000002|
 |3      |1          |1000000001|
 |4      |1          |1000000003|`

And i have **User** ActiveRecord Model:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord {
    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSubscribers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])->viaTable('subscribes', ['ref_user_id' => 'id'], function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy(['created_on' => SORT_DESC]);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, when i'm trying to get subscribers they are not sorted by subscribe time, they sorted by user id, that because viaTable not using JOIN but using WHERE IN condition.

```
$user = User::findOne(1);
$user->getSubscribers()->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

This code returning next sql code:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` IN ('3', '2', '4');
```

Please help me to sort subscribers by **created_on** column of **subscribers** table.

Answer (score 0):

In your model

```
public function getSubscribers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

in controller for retrieving data

```
$res = User::find()->joinWith('subscribes')->orderBy('subscribes.created_on');
```

Comment: I want to use that in ActiveDataProvider:
    `$subscribers = \Yii::createObject([
                'class' => ActiveDataProvider::className(),
                'query' => $model->getSubscribers(),
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => 10,
                ],
                'sort' => false,
            ])->getModels();`

Comment: @DmitryKorol If i understood correctly, You can also write your model like this: `$this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])->orderBy(['subscribes.created_on'=>SORT_DESC]);`